# Underline in pyQGIS

Tags: python, string, qgis, underline

I'm currently working on some university project on Qgis and I have to use Python to generate maps.

I would like to know if there is a way to underline str (like shown on the screenshot).

[Text rounded in red is the text I want to underline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7q0F.png)

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed with QGIS it is particular... Maybe it exists other methods, but I do that:

First, you will have to separate the text to underline, and the other text.

Then use **QtGui.QFont** to custom your font, and apply it to the wanted text, instead the former setFont.

Example:

```
...
from PyQt5 import *
...
myTitleBoldFont=QtGui.QFont("Verdana", 27)
myTitleBoldFont.setUnderline(True)
...
TextCustom.setFont(myBoldFont)
```

Do not forget to import **PyQt5**.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to use another solution that I found on pyQgis's doc. Here it is:

```
# Sous-titre

subtitle = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
subtitle.setMode(QgsLayoutItemLabel.Mode.ModeHtml)
subtitle.setText("<u>Coordonnées GPS :</u> " + (str(y_camping)) + " , " + (str(x_camping))+ " | <u>Téléphone :</u> "+str(tel_camping))
subtitle.setFont(b17)
subtitle.adjustSizeToText()
layout.addLayoutItem(subtitle)
subtitle.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(5, 19, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
```

The fact is that I just transform the label in html then the text contained in it can be underlined using < u >< /u > !